# How to automatically generate JAXB classes on build in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, xsd, jaxb

I have an IDEA project that uses auto-generated JAXB classes from .xsd files. I have “client” and “server” modules that include a “common” module that contains, among other things, the JAXB classes.

I do not want to keep generated code under source control, but if the generated java classes do not exist, “client” and “server” modules do not compile. How to make IntelliJ automatically run JAXB before building?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do it only with IntelliJ IDEA, you will need to use Ant or Maven or some other external process that will perform the code generation.

Check out [jaxb2-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html).

In IntelliJ IDEA you can execute Maven or Ant before compilation.

Comment: How am i supposed to execute Maven before compilation? Now it is but a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/171857).

Comment: It's just an example in case your project is already Maven based. If not, you should use some other command line way. Maybe someone will provide a better answer with the complete example, I'm just giving your the generic directions.

Answer (score 0):

In the build system's tool window you can bind a phase or a plugin goal to IDEA's build process.

For example the jaxb2-maven-plugin can be executed Before Rebuild or Before Build with a secondary click on the goal:

[image: Bind lifecycle phase to IDEA's build system]

Another option would be to bind the goal to a lifecycle phase and execute the phase like 'generate-sources' before rebuild. In case of the jaxb2-maven-plugin the goal [xjc](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/xjc-mojo.html) is by default bound to the generate-sources phase of Maven.